# How do I make a hyperlink in Slack Block Kit mrkdwn (markdown) block?

Tags: slack-block-kit

How can I make a link in a slack markdown block in Slack Block Kit?

I've tried what I'm used to using for markdown:

```
This is a [link](https://www.stackoverflow.com)
```

But that isn't working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Slack's Block Kit "mrkdwn" might be a bit different from what you are used to. You will need to do the following instead:

```
This is a <https://www.stackoverflow.com|link>
```

You can see this in action [in Slack's Block Kit Building](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/T024FM0NC#%7B%22blocks%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22this%20is%20a%20%3Chttps://www.stackoverflow.com%7Clink%3E%22%7D%7D%5D%7D) (you will need to sign in to a workspace)